# Composing boost::variant visitors for recursive variants

Tags: boost, boost-variant

I have an application with several boost::variants which share many of the fields.  I would  like to be able to compose these visitors into visitors for "larger" variants without copying and pasting a bunch of code.  It seems straightforward to do this for non-recursive variants, but once you have a recursive one, the self-references within the visitor (of course) point to the wrong class.  To make this concrete (and cribbing from the boost::variant docs):

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>

struct add;
struct sub;
template <typename OpTag> struct binop;

typedef boost::variant<
  int
  , boost::recursive_wrapper< binop<add> >
  , boost::recursive_wrapper< binop<sub> >
  > expression;

template <typename OpTag>
struct binop
{
  expression left;
  expression right;

  binop( const expression & lhs, const expression & rhs )
    : left(lhs), right(rhs)
  {
  }

};

// Add multiplication
struct mult;
typedef boost::variant<
  int
  , boost::recursive_wrapper< binop<add> >
  , boost::recursive_wrapper< binop<sub> >
  , boost::recursive_wrapper< binop<mult> >
  > mult_expression;

class calculator : public boost::static_visitor<int>
{
public:

  int operator()(int value) const
  {
    return value;
  }

  int operator()(const binop<add> & binary) const
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.left )
      + boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.right );
  }

  int operator()(const binop<sub> & binary) const
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.left )
      - boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.right );
  }

};

class mult_calculator : public boost::static_visitor<int>
{
public:

  int operator()(int value) const
  {
    return value;
  }

  int operator()(const binop<add> & binary) const
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.left )
      + boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.right );
  }

  int operator()(const binop<sub> & binary) const
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.left )
      - boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.right );
  }

  int operator()(const binop<mult> & binary) const
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.left )
      * boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.right );
  }

};

// I'd like something like this to compile
// class better_mult_calculator : public calculator
// {
// public:

//   int operator()(const binop<mult> & binary) const
//   {
//     return boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.left )
//       * boost::apply_visitor( *this, binary.right );
//   }

// };


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // result = ((7-3)+8) = 12
  expression result(binop<add>(binop<sub>(7,3), 8));

  assert( boost::apply_visitor(calculator(),result) == 12 );

  std::cout << "Success add" << std::endl;

  // result2 = ((7-3)+8)*2 = 12
  mult_expression result2(binop<mult>(binop<add>(binop<sub>(7,3), 8),2));
  assert( boost::apply_visitor(mult_calculator(),result2) == 24 );

  std::cout << "Success mult" << std::endl;
}
```

I would really like something like that commented out  better_mult_expression to compile (and work) but it doesn't -- because the `this` pointers within the base calculator visitor don't reference mult_expression, but expression.

Does anyone have suggestions for overcoming this or am I just barking down the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest the variant to include all possible node types, not distinguishing between `mult` and `expression`. This distinction makes no sense at the AST level, only at a parser stage (if you implement operator precedence in recursive/PEG fashion).

Other than that, here's a few observations:

- if you encapsulate the `apply_visitor` dispatch into your evaluation functor you can reduce the code duplication by a big factor
- your real question seems not to be about composing variants, but composing *visitors*, more specifically, by inheritance.

  You can use `using` to pull inherited overloads into scope for overload resolution, so this might be the most direct answer:

  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e105060efd11a1f)**

  ```
   struct better_mult_calculator : calculator {
       using calculator::operator();

       auto operator()(const binop<mult>& binary) const
       {
           return boost::apply_visitor(*this, binary.left) *
               boost::apply_visitor(*this, binary.right);
       }
   };
  ```

### IMPROVING!

Starting from [that listing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e105060efd11a1f) let's shave off some noise!

1. remove unncessary AST distinction ([-40 lines, down to 55 lines of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d17438e3e277575f))
2. generalize the operations; the `<functional>` header comes standard with these:

   ```
   namespace AST {
       template <typename> struct binop;
       using add  = binop<std::plus<>>;
       using sub  = binop<std::minus<>>;
       using mult = binop<std::multiplies<>>;
       using expr = boost::variant<int,
           recursive_wrapper<add>,
           recursive_wrapper<sub>,
           recursive_wrapper<mult>>;

       template <typename> struct binop { expr left, right; };
   } // namespace AST
   ```

   Now the entire `calculator` can be:

   ```
   struct calculator : boost::static_visitor<int> {
       int operator()(int value) const { return value; }

       template <typename Op> 
       int operator()(AST::binop<Op> const& binary) const {
           return Op{}(boost::apply_visitor(*this, binary.left),
                       boost::apply_visitor(*this, binary.right));
       }
   };
   ```

   Here your variant can add arbitrary operations without even needing to touch the calculator.

   **[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c1692553d01255d)**, 43 Lines Of Code
3. Like I mentioned starting off, encapsulate visitation!

   ```
   struct Calculator {
       template <typename... T> int operator()(boost::variant<T...> const& v) const {
           return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
       }

       template <typename T> 
       int operator()(T const& lit) const { return lit; }

       template <typename Op> 
       int operator()(AST::binop<Op> const& bin) const {
           return Op{}(operator()(bin.left), operator()(bin.right));
       }
   };
   ```

   Now you can just call your calculator, like intended:

   ```
   Calculator calc;
   auto result1 = calc(e1);
   ```

   It will work when you extend the variant with operatios or even other literal types (like e.g. `double`). It will even work, regardless of whether you pass it an incompatible variant type that holds a subset of the node types.
4. To finish that off for maintainability/readability, I'd suggest making `operator()` only a dispatch function:

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e4a4c0ccae14aa3)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace AST {
    using boost::recursive_wrapper;

    template <typename> struct binop;
    using add  = binop<std::plus<>>;
    using sub  = binop<std::minus<>>;
    using mult = binop<std::multiplies<>>;
    using expr = boost::variant<int,
        recursive_wrapper<add>,
        recursive_wrapper<sub>,
        recursive_wrapper<mult>>;

    template <typename> struct binop { expr left, right; };
} // namespace AST

struct Calculator {
    auto operator()(auto const& v) const { return call(v); }

  private:
    template <typename... T> int call(boost::variant<T...> const& v) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }

    template <typename T> 
    int call(T const& lit) const { return lit; }

    template <typename Op> 
    int call(AST::binop<Op> const& bin) const {
        return Op{}(call(bin.left), call(bin.right));
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace AST;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    auto sub_expr = add{sub{7, 3}, 8};
    expr e1       = sub_expr;
    expr e2       = mult{sub_expr, 2};

    Calculator calc;

    auto result1 = calc(e1);
    std::cout << "result1:  " << result1 << " Success? " << (12 == result1) << "\n";

    // result2 = ((7-3)+8)*2 = 12
    auto result2 = calc(e2);
    std::cout << "result2:  " << result2 << " Success? " << (24 == result2) << "\n";
}
```

Still prints

```
result1:  12 Success? true
result2:  24 Success? true
```